# proving that $f(z)=1/\Gamma(z)$ is a entire function

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function, holomorphic-functions, entire-functions

$\Gamma: \mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is the gamma function and $g:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $g(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ is the reciprocal.

We know that these functions aren't entire but $\Gamma \in \mathbb{H}(\mathbb{C}\backslash\{0,-1,...\})$ and $g\in \mathbb{H}(\mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\})$, so if i prove that $\Gamma $ has no zero is enough to say that $f=g\times \Gamma: \mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is entire?

Comment: No, that's not enough: $e^{1/z}$ doesn't have a zero, but the reciprocal is not entire.

Comment: What exactly are you not sure about ? You can show $\Gamma$ has no zeros from the reflection formula $\Gamma(s) \Gamma(1-s) = \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi s)}$ by showing $\Gamma(s) \Gamma(1-s) - \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi s)} $ is a $2$-periodic entire function which is bounded on $\Re(s) \in [0,2]$

Comment: @ProfessorVector but in the poles of the $\Gamma$ $f$ is well defined and its $0$. What do i need more to prove that its entire?

Comment: It's exactly that: the singularities of $\Gamma$ aren't essential singularities, they are poles.

Comment: Did you try what I said ? The integral representation, $\Gamma(1) = 1$ and $\Gamma(s+1) = s \Gamma(s)$ implies $\Gamma(s) \Gamma(1-s) - \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi s)}$ is a $2$-periodic entire function and it is bounded on $\Re(s) \in [0,2]$, thus it is constant by Liouville theorem.

Comment: @reuns, yes i've already proved that fact, i just want now complements to affirm $f$ is entire

Comment: Hmm... It is much more trivial that what I said. If $f$ is meromorphic around $z=a$ then $\frac{1}{f(z)}$ is analytic around $z=a$ iff $f(a) \ne 0$. $e^{1/z}$ is not meromorphic at $z=0$. Meromorphic means $(z-a)^k f(z)$ is analytic for some $k$.